# define subset in GAMS

Tags: optimization, programming

I have a problem about partitioning . with 3 set $i,j,k$ , $i=1,..,32 $ Represents the number of classes, $j=1,..,512 $ Represents the number of student, $k=1,..,40 $ Represents the type of student.

set $j=\{ 1,...,512\}$ , and subsets $t_k$ of $j$ ,Which indicates   student $j$th belongs to which type. for example , if we consider type $k=1$, then  all student with type $'1'$ are $t_1= \{ 2,10,78,69,114,500\}$.

These subsets are known. for example $t_1= \{ 2,10,78,69,114,500\}$  and $t_2=\{8,42,50\}$ ,...

I want to code in gams this  sum in GAMS , $ \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x_{i,j} \   \   \   \ \forall i , \   \   j\in t_k$

I know when we want to use subset we can write

```
set j / 1*512/,
    t(j)
```

but in this case, The subset has already been specified  .

i use this way

```
set
     j/1*512/
     t(j)/2,10,78,69,114,500/
     ;
```

its right for one case "$t_1$ "

I don't know how can I define this type of subset such that Work for all sub set, and how can I define this summation?

Comment: $\forall j \in t_j$ is not a valid mathematical expression.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen hello , Right to you, it was a typo mistake. I corrected it

Comment: Well, $j \in t_j$ remains non-sensical. This is like $j \in \{1,..,j\}$ or $\sum_{j=1}^j x_j$. All these have no meaning.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen It was not originally in this form, I wrote this way. In fact, it was $t_k$ such that $k $ is other set $k=\{1,...,40\} $and $ t_k $ is a set that indicate student with type k. i write it this way because i think However,when we use $t_k$ we have a subset of j . right?

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen I corrected the question. Thanks for your note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first few iterations of this question the math was just wrong. It is no surprise that in that case the translation into GAMS is very difficult.

Now we have:

```
sets
    i 'classes' /class1*class32/
    j 'students' /student1*student512/
    k 'student type' /type1*type40/
;
```

Of course for a real model the set elements would have proper meaning, like:

```
set i 'classes' /English,Biology,Math/;
```

Now, we can do:

```
set t(k,j) 'mapping between type and student' /
   type1.(student2,student10,student78,student69,student114,student500)
   type2.(student8,student42,student50)
/;
```

We can use this in expressions as

```
equation 
   e(k).. v(k) =e= sum((i,j)$t(k,j), a(i,j)*x(i,j));
```

This would correspond to:

$$v_k = \sum_{i,j|t(k,j)} a_{i,j} x_{i,j}$$

I.e. $ is a 'such-that' operator, just like | in math.

Comment: Thank you very much, your response is very helpful. Thanks

Comment: hello , my equation  is $x(i,j) <= y(i,k) \forall  i, k   $and $j \in t_k$

Comment: e(i,k,j) = x(i,j)$t(k,j)<=y(i,k) is right?  i think it is not right

Comment: how can write equation 1 $x_{i,j} \le y_{ik} \forall i,k $ and  $j\in t_k$    and equation 2  $ y_{ik} \le \sum_{j\in t_k} x_{ij}$   ,Please, if you can help, I tried it, but it is wrong